# Inverse distribution of an RV

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Consider the Random Variable $X $ given by PDF $f (x)=0$ if $x\le 0$,  $f (x)=1/2$ if $0\le x\le 1$, and $f (x)=1/(2x^2)$ if $1<x\le\infty$. I wish to determine the cumulative distribution function $F_Y$ of the RV $Y=1/X$.

I can find out Pr $(Y\le x)$ if $x>0$ but am confused how to proceed when $x <0$. It seems to me Pr $(Y\le x)$ for $x<0$ is $1-F_X(1/x)=1$ but this is wrong as $F_X$ is no longer increasing.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=0$ for $x \leq 0$ means that $X$ is a positive random variable. Hence $Y$ is also positive, so $P\{Y\leq x\}=0$ if $x <0$.

Comment: But is a mathematical justification possible? I want to interpret Y as a composition of X with the reiprocal function

Comment: @Shahab You are making the mistake of thinking that $\frac 1 X \leq x$ is same as $X \geq \frac 1 x$. This is false. For example, $\frac 1 1 $ is not $\leq -1$ even though $1 \geq \frac 1 {-1}$. Incidentally, my answer is Mathematical and rigorous.

Comment: In your example the two sides have different signs. Here $x,X <0$ and so $1/X\le x $ is the same event as $X\ge 1/x$. (If $X $ is positive then the corresponding event is the empty set.) Are you saying that for  $X <0$ the event $X\ge 1/x$ is a null event?

Comment: Yes of course. I realize now that $1/x\le X <0$ has probability $\int_{1/x}^0f(x)dx=0$

Comment: Is it true in general that if $X$ is an RV with PDF $f$ such that $f(x)=0$ for $x\le 0$ then the PDF $h$ of $g\circ X$ has $h(x)=0$ for $x\le 0$ for any Borel measurable function $g$? If so, what is the proof?

Comment: No, this is not true. (If $g$ is a negative function this will certainly fail). The function $g(x)=\frac 1 x$ has the property that it is positive when $x$ is positive. For such functions the implication holds.

Comment: Thank you. Can you recommend a book in which results of this kind are proved very rigorously?